# Optionals with unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, java-8, option-type

Consider the following code:

```
auditlog.getMessages()
    .stream()
    .filter(m -> messageId.equals(m.getMessageid()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(NoMessageFoundException::new)
```

`NoMessageFoundException` is a custom unchecked exception, extending from `RuntimeException`. When `findFirst()` returns an empty optional I expect a `NoMessageFoundException` to be thrown, however, the code just carries on.

Is it impossible to do this with unchecked exceptions?

I could change `NoMessageFoundException` to a checked exception, but then I would have to write a `try/catch` block or some sort of wrapper to catch the exception as explained [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions) but I wish to not do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Implementing `Supplier<RuntimeException>`  causes the lambda to return a compilcation error. `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert MappingFailedException to xxx`

Comment: your code look ok to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation on the type of Exception that can be thrown.

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X {
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

If the code "carries on", it means that a message is found.

Answer (score 1):

if the exception is not getting throw is because there is at least one element remaining after the filter action...

see this example:

```
public class ASFasf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        Integer iR = l.stream().filter(x -> x > 100).findFirst().orElseThrow(NoMessageFoundException::new);
        System.out.println(iR);
    }
}

class NoMessageFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public NoMessageFoundException() {
        super("Opala!!");
    }
}
```

iR will never get printed, and a `NoMessageFoundException` is thrown....